# Attaching a "Free Download" button to the SoundCloud player within the SoundCloud website

Tags: widget, soundcloud

This problem has eluded me for over a month now. I've noticed certain SoundCloud(SC) members are able to attach a button that says "Free Download" (or some variation of that) onto the SC player within the SC site. I've seen that you can customize the SC widget for embedding elsewhere, but I'm stumped on how to edit it on SC. Any ideas or help in figuring this out would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a web application.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a SoundCloud Premium account http://soundcloud.com/premium then you are able to rename the 'Buy Link' title. It can be done on the 'Edit' page of a track or a set.